# CSS Как добавить икнонку

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как добавить иконки в блок, сделать чтобы все 4 блока были одинаковыми и не разъезжались, когда в них добавляется текст? Желательно с объяснением, как такое лучше делать вообще, я только учусь. Спасибо.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

.logo a {
  padding: 16px 25px;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 54px;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}

.nav a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 13px Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff7200;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  top: 38px;
  color: #ff7200;
  /* Цвет ссылки при наведении на нее курсора мыши */
}

#home {
  background: #222 url(../img/Background.jpg) no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 968px;
}

.title h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 60px Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 445px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.title h5 {
  font: 18px Raleway, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  margin-left: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 170px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff7200;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.button a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 13px Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#web {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 1428px;
  width: 1170px;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

div #web .class {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav2 {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding-left: 383px;
}

.nav2 li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.nav2 li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}

.nav2 a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 16px Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav2 ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 125px 78px 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #444444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 54px 133px 0 133px;
  border-color: #eeeeee transparent transparent transparent;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff7200;
}

.link:hover:after {
  border-top-color: #ff7200;
}

.link2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 125px 78px 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #444444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 54px 130px 0 130px;
  border-color: #eeeeee transparent transparent transparent;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.link2:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff7200;
}

.link2:hover:after {
  border-top-color: #ff7200;
}

.link3 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 125px 78px 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #444444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link3:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 54px 152px 0 152px;
  border-color: #eeeeee transparent transparent transparent;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.link3:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff7200;
}

.link3:hover:after {
  border-top-color: #ff7200;
}

.link4 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 125px 78px 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #444444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link4:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 54px 137px 0 137px;
  border-color: #eeeeee transparent transparent transparent;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.link4:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff7200;
}

.link4:hover:after {
  border-top-color: #ff7200;
}
```

```html
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700');
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo" name="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/logo1.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="home">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title" name="title">
        <h1>Welcome to our logic</h1>
        <h5>We Make Awesome Theme For Your Business</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="button" name="button">
        <center><a href="#">Get Started</a></center>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="web" class="web">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav2">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link2">App Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link3">Graphic Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link4">Game Design</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Нужно сделать так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgdAY.jpg)

[у меня получается вот так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KLVs.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Не используйте `position: absolute` там где это не нужно, к тому же не понимая, что это и как работает.
2. Что бы на размер блоков не влиял их контент им нужно задать ширину.
   В вашем случае у вас 4 пункта, которым можно задать относительную ширину с помощью функции `calc((100% - 90px) / 4)` учитывая отступы.
3. Иконку вставляем в ссылку перед текстом.
   Для выравнивания используем `flex` - один из возможных вариантов
4. Моё мнение, если элементы меню будут responsive(хоть немного менять свои размеры), то лучше сделать ее через `clip-path` или `svg`.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav2 {
  width: 100%;
  //border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.nav2 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav2 ul::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
.nav2 li {
  float: left;
  width: calc((100% - 90px) / 4);
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.nav2 li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}


.link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #444444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 16px Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}

.link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff7200;
}

.link:hover:after {
  background-color: #ff7200;
}
.icon {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700');
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="web" class="web">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav2">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="link link1"><span class="icon"><img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/50x50" alt=""></span> Web Design Web Design Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link link2"><span class="icon"><img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/50x50" alt=""></span> App Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link link3"><span class="icon"><img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/50x50" alt=""></span> Graphic Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link link4"><span class="icon"><img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/50x50" alt=""></span> Game Design</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В простыню не вчитывался, но однозначно есть три железобетонных решения:

1. через тег img
2. через background
3. через псевдоэлемент+background

Во всех трех вариантах иконку позиционируем абсолютно, что и дает независимость от текста...